# [next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR], how to fix this error in next-auth

Tags: mongoose, next.js, error-handling, next-auth

i am using next-auth for myy nextjs web application. in local development my application are working fine but the bellow error thrown in production build. how to fix this issues. i will try different methods for fixing that issues, but still cant fixed this issue.

```
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms {
  message: 'Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms',
  stack: 'MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms\n' +
    '    at Timeout.<anonymous> (G:\\Next project\\videoclay\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\drivers\\node-mongodb-native\\collection.js:186:23)\n' +
    '    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)\n' +
    '    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)',
  name: 'MongooseError'
}
```

mongo database connection.

db.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const connection = {};
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);


async function connectDb() {
    if (connection.isConnected){
        console.log('Already connected to the database');
        return;
    }

    if (mongoose.connections.length > 0) {
        connection.isConnected = mongoose.connections[0].readyState;
        if (connection.isConnected === 1) {
            console.log('Use existing connection');
            return;
        }
        await mongoose.disconnect();
    }

    const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    console.log('New connection to the database');
    connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
}

async function disconnectDb() {
    if (connection.isConnected) {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
            await mongoose.disconnect();
            connection.isConnected = false;
        } else {
            console.log('Not disconnected');
        }
    }
}

const db = { connectDb, disconnectDb };

export default db;
```

mongo database connation for next-auth

mongodb.js

```
import {MongoClient} from "mongodb";

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
const options = {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    // useNewUrlParser: true,
};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URL) {
    throw new Error("Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local");
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
        client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
        global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
    }
    clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    clientPromise = client.connect();
}

export default clientPromise;
```

[next-auth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import User from "../../../models/User";
import clientPromise from "./lib/mongodb";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import db from "../../../utils/db";
import {MongoDBAdapter} from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";

export default NextAuth({
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const email = credentials.email;
                const password = credentials.password;
                await db.connectDb();
                const user = await User.findOne({ email });
                if (user) {
                    return SignInUser({ password, user });
                } else {
                    throw new Error("This email does not exist.");
                }
            },
        }),
        FacebookProvider({
            clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
        }),
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token }) {
            const user = await User.findById(token.sub);
            session.user.id = token.sub || user._id.toSting();
            session.user.role = user.role || "user";
            token.role = user.role || "user";

            return session;
        },
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: "/signin",
    },
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
});

const SignInUser = async ({ password, user }) => {
    if (!user.password) {
        throw new Error("Please enter your password.");
    }
    const testPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!testPassword) {
        throw new Error("Email or password is wrong!");
    }
    return user;
};
```